# Spring mvc + Security Pdf showing blank

Tags: java, spring-mvc, pdf, spring-security

We are trying on one of our project and trying to give download of one pdf document.

Following is our code in controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/usermanual", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getFile(HttpServletRequest req,

    HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
    {


    try {
      // get your file as InputStream
        File file = new File(req.getRealPath("/")+"js/loginPage/usermanual.pdf");
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

        /*BufferedOutputStream stream =
                new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("E:/Backups/p.pdf")));
        org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(is, stream);

        stream.close();*/
        // Response header
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=123.pdf");
      // copy it to response's OutputStream
      org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
      response.setContentType("application/pdf");
      response.flushBuffer();
      response.getOutputStream().close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {

      throw new RuntimeException("IOError writing file to output stream");
    }

}
```

The file is made in E directory so File copying is not issue on local disk but in response.getOutputStream it has some issue.

We are getting blank pdf as a result.

Please provide some guidelines in this case. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is because the InputStream is consumed by the 1st copy, you need to open a new InputStream for the 2nd copy.

Comment: I commented it but still it is showing blank pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `flush` before `close` of the `OutputStream`.

```
  response.getOutputStream().flush();
```

Or If you are using Spring MVC 4.2 you can make use of `StreamingResponseBody`

```
public StreamingResponseBody stream(HttpServletRequest req)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File(req.getRealPath("/")+"js/loginPage/usermanual.pdf");
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
    return (os) -> {
        IOUtils.copy(is, os);
    };
}
```

For more information see this [post](http://shazsterblog.blogspot.com/2016/02/asynchronous-streaming-request.html)